# I can't remove Git Large File from repository history

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-rewrite-history, revision-history

I've a repository that was migrated from Mercurial to Git in the past, and this repository is on BitBucket.
Now I need to move from BitBucket to GitHub, but GitHub saying to me that exists a big file, bigger than 100mb. I can find the branch of file with `git log --all -- *MQ.rar`, but when I execute the command to remove the file `git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch *MQ.rar' -- --all`, the file isn't removed.

I used the "Find Large Files" plugin on "Git Extensions", but the file isn't listed.

Maybe could be something with the file path that have acentuation?!

I don't know what can I do to solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history.  The answers to that question should resolve your issue. While that Q was specifically interested in sensitive data, the solutions also work for big files.  [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14656358/5411817) specifically addresses large files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove sensitive files and their commits from Git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history)

Answer (score -1):

This can be an answer to your problem. I've deleted some sensitive data with the help of this [repo](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner). It basically deletes the files from your history and you need to make a push in the end. At Readme's most down part, there is a link that will guide you through.

Comment: This is a comment, not a complete self-contained answer as per SO guidelines. See top topics in stackoverflow.com/help for more info.